# How do I create a digital timing diagram based on D flip-flop signals?

Tags: flipflop, latch, diagram

We are constructing a D flip-flop using 2 latches and a control-signal coming from a clock.

The flip flop looks like this (x1 and x2 are connected to two switches, L1 and L2 are standard latches connected in a Master-Slave order):

[image]

The control circuit looks like this:

[image]

I have connected and tested this on a circuit board and it works as intended.

So when the clock is at 0 the Φ-signals are as follows: $$clk = 0 \longrightarrow (Φ_1, Φ_2) = (0, 1)$$ And when clocking it to 1 the signal is: $$clk = 1 \longrightarrow (Φ_1, Φ_2) = (1, 0)$$

Now on the circuit board this switch is instantaneous. However, we are supposed to fill out a timing diagram that explains how the change is happening. For starters we now have that when clk is 0 at the start Φ2 should be 1 and Φ1 should be 0. When it clocks, how should I know which signal changes first, and which resulting signal then changes second? Is it dependent on which gate got cross-wired first? If not, how should I approach this?

[image]

Comment: What did your instructor say? If you want to get maximum points you need to do what the instructor says, not what some random person on the internet tells you.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Well obviously it's an assignment so they won't reveal too much.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

1. label and draw every signal including the outputs of the three NOTs
2. pick an arbitrary starting state clk=0
3. imagine it's been like that for ever

   1. is that enough to know Φ1 or Φ2?
   2. is that enough to know the whole state?
4. now consider the case when clk changes to 1
5. then, consider that it must take a little time for the NOT or AND gate to change (look up propagation delay, for your 74HC series, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400-series_integrated_circuits))
6. In particular, look at the top gate.

If you can't do it in your head, do it on a piece of paper.

Comment: The question I'm wondering most about is how I know which phi signal will change first? Since they are cross-wired how can I figure it out? We are using 74HC series.

Comment: Look at the top gate, top input.  Immediately after clk changes to 1, **is that enough information to know the output?**.  And, **immediately** after clk changes to 1, have the outputs of the NOT gates changed?

Comment: The first points I get. But the problem is with the last one. According to some doc I found (https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/hd74hc-series-common-information) the delay is approx 6 nanoseconds.

Comment: Well before clk changes the phi2 signal is 0. So when clk changes we know the in will be (clk, phi2) = (1, 0) so the out will be 0 (phi1+) phi1+ will be inverted and sent to phi2 which in will be (clk, phi1+) = (0, 1) phi2+ will be 0 then inverted and sent to phi1 which new in will be (clk, phi2+) = (1, 1) phi1+ is now 1 and sent to phi2 all over again. It seems that here is a circular thing going on here... Or am I just failing in grasping the logic?

Comment: You're failing to **simulate** the circuit in your head, you're **jumping to the conclusion** of what the gates will be by thinking of them as mathematical units.  Honestly, do it as I said: label all six points in the circuit and follow my suggestion.  Try acting out the top AND or the left NOT filming yourself in slow motion.

Comment: I updated the image. We only have NAND-gates so this new one makes the inverted signals redundant. Shouldn't make your method different though.

Comment: I can only repeat myself: **LABEL and DRAW all six points** and think about them in the way I said.  (And I suggest you stick with the original diagram, it's a little easier.)

Comment: That is what I've been doing. I guess the point is to pause at every simultaneous gate instance and look at the ouputs. The first will be the top NAND and the left NOT. Next will be top right NOT and bottom NAND, next will be top NAND and bottom right NOT. Or am I still failing to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139640/discussion-between-jonathanjo-and-felix9801).